# Large SQL statement versus a few data calls

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have a web page where I need to get fields from many tables in SQL that can all join. Is it better in terms of performance to do a few queries to the database or one big SQL statement. I'm using MVC with Web API calls.

Thanks.

Comment: simple answer: it totally depends... how many fields/how many records/how many joins/... test both cases

Comment: thanks. I will test, other than performance, is there one way that's more correct programmatically? If my sql statement will need to return 100 columns is that bad design?

Comment: again: it totally depends... 10 vs. 100.000 records. in a webpage, I´d try to keep the amount of transferred-data as low as possible!

Comment: I've usually found it is better to move the data all in on call, as opposed to calling multiple times for each piece of data.  Finally, what some guys have done on a system I'm working on, they made a stored procedure with multiple queries to populate variables, then they ended with a single SELECT of all their populated variables - did they find that to be faster than a join?  It means SQL executes multiple queries, but it all gets passed back through a single call to a service.

Comment: @SanchoPanza It's returning one record with 100 columns

Comment: @Cato Is that something you would recommend as opposed to a few data calls?

Comment: I would try returning 100 columns before I resorted to calling a web service or API 100 times, yes

Comment: Thanks! I bring it back and populate an object though  - that means my object will have 100 properties - is that bad design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've created DB Views to define the data I'm looking for.  Depending on the data access framework you are using this can also be helpful in returning the data and translating it to objects.

As far as performance goes, I'm most familiar with SQL Server, and in the Management Studio there is an option to "Include Actual Execution Plan".  This will show you a full breakdown of your JOIN statements, what indexes are being used if any, and will suggest indexes to speed performance.  I recommend this tool to all developers on my teams when they are stuck with a slow performing page.

One other thing to note, the database configuration also makes a difference.  If you are running a local database you will have fewer concerns than if you were running a cloud based database (Azure SQL, etc) as those have management overhead beyond your control when it comes to availability and physical location of your instance at any given time.